# check if Activity is in Stack if up button is pressed in Android

Tags: android

How can I check if a designated `Activity` is in Stack and if not start them.

```
case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
```

As you can see, now it just finishes the current `Activity` and normally it would show the Activity that is started before.
So it looks like:

activity1 -> activity2 -> activity 3

I want to skip activity2 and if the user wants to go up from activity3 to activity2, then it has to be started.

I hope it's clear what I want to do, if not just ask!

Kind Regards!

Comment: cant you just `finish()` activity 2 and start activity 3 and when user goes up from activity 3 start activity 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using [Intent flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) by adding any of them before starting the designated activity using intent

For example if you're in activity 3 and want to go to activity 2 and if its already in stack bring it to front you can use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) flag

which as documented will bring existing activity to top if present

Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(..);
intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

..

But if you seriously want to access the activity stack AFAIK its not possible as described [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351688/android-access-the-activity-stack-programmatically), but you can achieve the bahaviour otherwise..

for example, if you want to keep track of activity 2 you can add a a variable in your Application that indicated whether or not the activity 2 is present and use that information to build upon.

Comment: That's unfortunately not what I want. What can I do to check if the activity2 is in stack or is still active?

Comment: From your post I get the message that you're trying to bring activity 2 to front if it already exists and if not start it from "scratch" which is exactly what that flag is going to do

If not, please clarify what you're going to do

Comment: Ps. updated the answer to include information regarding accessing activity stack

Comment: Okay I will explain what I want. `SplashScreen` -> `LogInScreen` -> `WorkActivity`. I want to skip LogInScreen if the User is already logged in and go directly to WorkActivity. If the User presses the up button, I want to open the LogInScreen. In case it's the first time the User opens the app, the stack looks like follows: `SplashScreen`->LogInS..->WorkA... so I cant really use a Intent because the `LogInScreen`is already in stack right?

Comment: By "up" button, you mean "back button"? How come you don't just spawn new LogInScreen after person pressed the backbutton? like so: start spash screen -> finish splash screen and if user is logged in show work activity and if not show login screen -> if user presses back button in work activity finish and show login screen -> and loop.
On top of that this seems like a custom navigation behaviour which most likely will confuse your users and is not adviced